# mysql don't connect to Ultimate intelleg idea

Tags: mysql, sql, intellij-idea

I'm new to Linux and my problem is that I can start mysql through the console and work in it, but I can't connect to the ultimate intellege idea. Gives this error message (The specified database user / password combination is rejected: [28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root' @ 'localhost' (using password: YES))
in the console, this problem was solved by adding sudo to the connection to mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBYdh.png)

Comment: how do you connect from the console? Share the whole code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you had to do was create another user and give him all the privileges from the database